# How do I update same published node for future use?

Tags: nodes

I want to create/update nodes in Drupal 7 like Oracle WCS(webCenter sites). In that there are two servers, Managed and Delivery Server. In Managed server content can be created and after getting approved by other users like publisher, it can be published to Delivery server. So, it will be live. At the same time they can update content for future use. (Now this is updated in Managed server.) Whenever they want to make it live, they will just get it approved and publish it again. For author/content creator it seems same content which he is updating and which is live.

Can we achieve this kind of functionality in Drupal 7?  I tried to use the Node clone module, but it creates copy of a node with different node ID. Client just don't want to create a copy of same node for updating. Same node which is live we should update but will publish in future.

Comment: I think what you're talking about is revisioning. There are plenty modules for that, for example https://www.drupal.org/project/revisioning or https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation .

Comment: My requirement was, to update node content which is published but that changes should not reflect on site without approving by authorized user. Workbench module perfectly fit for my requirement. In that I can use workflow and all basic requirement things.

Thanks All !